# Chess Game in Java: Should Square Class Have "Generate Possible Moves" Method?

Tags: java

I'm writing a chess game. My basic design is to have a 2d array (8 x 8) consisting of square objects. Squares have a number of fields: int height, int width, Piece piece (null if empty, some type of Piece object otherwise.

NB: Rook, Knight, Bishop, etc. all extend Piece.

Now, I'm getting a little tripped up on how to figure out what moves are legal for a given piece, given my OOP design.  Here's what I'm thinking:

1) User clicks square
2) We determine what piece is on square (if empty, return error message)
3) Generate legal moves for that piece on that square

I'm worried about writing code like:

```
if (clickedSquare.piece.instanceOf(Rook)) {
    return Rook.getLegalDestinationSquares(clickedSquare);
} else if (clickedSquare.piece.instanceOf(Bishop)) {
    return Bishop.getLegalDestinationSquares(clickedSquare);
} else if...
```

Which seems really bad.  There must be a way to do this that conforms better to OOP but I'm still learning.

Thanks for the help,
Mariogs

Comment: Is your code compiling? Basically you are defining factory... so what's wrong with it?

Comment: how about `clickedSquare.piece.getLegalDestinationSquares(clickedSquare)` ? i.e. create an overloaded method defined in each subtype of `Piece`

Comment: I would put isLegalMove(Piece, Square) to the ChessBoard class.

Comment: Make an abstract parent that has the method `getLegalDestinationSquares` and have each of your different pieces implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create that *if* statement. Just get the current piece on the field and call some method like (getLegalMoves()) or something.
If field is empty - return empty list of allowed moves.

```
public abstract class Piece {

    public abstract List<Field> getFieldsAllowed(Field field);
}
public class Rook extends Piece {

    @Override
    public List<Field> getFieldsAllowed(Field field) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }    
}
public class Field {

    public Piece getPiece() {
        // get current piece
    }
}
```

Something like this. Try to find your own solution. This one is not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

```
public final class Point {
    public final int x, y;

    public Point (int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

public abstract class Piece {
    private Point location;

    protected Piece (Point initial){
        this.location = initial;
    }

    public Point getLocation(){ return location; }

    public Point setLocation(Point location){ this.location = location; }

    public abstract List<Point> getLegalMoves ();
}

public final class Rook {
    public Rook (Point initial){
        super(initial);
    }

    public List<Point> getLegalMoves (){
         // you know the current location, and you know you are a Rook,
         // so you have all you need to determine the possible points where
         // this Rook can go to
    }
}
```

Then in other code, you can do:

```
List<Point> legalMoves = clickedSquare.piece.getLegalMoves();
```

which clearly makes abstraction of what actual piece it is acting upon.

If you do need a static method for other purposes, you can define them in each class such as Rook. Delegate the instance methods to the static methods to avoid code duplication. Like this:

```
public final class Rook {
    // constructor etc.

    public List<Point> getLegalMoves (){
         return Rook.getLegalMoves (getLocation());
    }

    public static List<Point> getLegalMoves(Point start){
         // you know the location (start), and you know this method is for a Rook,
         // so you have all you need to determine the possible end points
    }
}
```

However, if you do not need that static method, don't use and don't even write it (or at least don't expose it in the API of the class). Users of your classes will otherwise start to abuse it end will end up writing code as you provided in your start post - those countless if-elses.

By using this solution, you can add more concrete subclasses (`Pawn`, `King`, ...) in the future without touching any existing code (that now acts on `Piece`), which gives you a maintainability advantage compared to your provided approach.

Answer (score 0):

If Rook, Bishop etc are:

```
public class Rook extends Piece {
    @Override
    public String getLegalDestinationSquares() {
       // returns all leagal Rook squers 
       return null;
    }
}
```

and Piece is:

```
public abstract class Piece {
    public abstract String getLegalDestinationSquares();
}
```

Then you might do it like (in your sample):

```
return clickedSquare.piece.getLegalDestinationSquares();
```

Return String is just example, probably you should return Collection of squares.

Answer (score 0):

From OOD there are a few critics.

1. a field is a field even if no figure is on the field. A null-filed therefore does not exists ([LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle))!
2. a figure do never know what moves he can do, this must be set only by the game rules. Create a new class called `Rules`. Its the responsibility of the rules to know what moves he can do([SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)). A King (for example) must know if he already did a Castling to decide if he can do a Castling, therefore he must know the previous moves, and this breaks the [DIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) - ah, here we have another class we miss: `ChessNotation`.
3. instanceof is usefull when you inherit things, a Rook can not inherit a field ([LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle),[DIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)).